# Output of data from one component in the other component . Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I need a help. I have 1 parent component. There are five children in it. This is one page with cards. Each card is a component. In one card, I upload a csv-file to the server and the server immediately gives me the json, which I need to display in the other cards (in the form of tables, graphs) without additional get-requests. In fact, clicked on the send button, the file was gone and then it appears in all the components. Get and post-requests I do through the service. I don`t understand how I can transmit data through the service to all components. Thank you in advance.

I have simple http.service.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getData() {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080');
    }
    postData(data: any) {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080', data, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
      })
    }
}
```

and children component, which uploading file to server

```
export class SignalsComponent {
  selectedFile: File = null;
  addFileStatus = false;
  progressBar: any;
  signalsFiles: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}
  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    this.addFileStatus = true;
  }
  sendCsvFile() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('csv-file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.postData(formData)
      .subscribe(event => {
        if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.progressBar = 'Upload Progress: ' + Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100) + '%';
        } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.signalsFiles = event.body;
          console.log(this.signalsFiles);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's a good idea to add your code to the question, so we have some context. What have you tried already?

Comment: my code is at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create an observable within your service. When you make the HTTP request, you can then send that response out via the observable, so that any subscribers will be notified. The service would look something like this:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  private _dataChanged = new Subject<any>();

  // Components can subscribe to this
  public onDataChanged = this._dataChanged.asObservable()

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public loadData() {
    // Emit the data here
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
      .subscribe((data) => this._dataChanged.next(data));
  }

}
```

Your components can subscribe to the onDataChanged observable like so:

```ts
constructor(private service: ExampleService) {
    this.service.onDataChanged.subscribe((data) => this.data = data);
}
```

As soon as one of your components calls `loadData()`, all of the subscribers will be notified with the results.

Here is a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gueraq?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm going to try now

Comment: I did it :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help. If it solved your problem, please remember to accept this as the answer. Thanks